# mysql stored proc - will deadlock cause performance?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Will deadlock cause performance issues like delay execution time ?

Answer (score 1):

Deadlocks prevent queries from running because of a clash over resources. The only usual way for a database engine to handle deadlocks is to kill one of the processes in the deadlock and if possible, rerun it.

So, yes a deadlock will cause performance problems as the engine will have to detect the deadlock and then handle it. Generally it's good practice to avoid deadlocks as much as possible.

There is lots of information here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

Comment: InnoDB doesn't rerun the transaction automatically - it returns an error to the application. The application needs to retry itself.

Answer (score 1):

When you get a deadlock, one of the transactions involved gets rolled back. Rolling back a transaction is relatively expensive for the server, and consumes effort it would otherwise spend on real work; moreover, the original transaction then needs to be done again.

However, you should aim to have a very small number of deadlocks in your application. If 1% of transactions deadlock, it may be too many.

Fortunately, the designers of InnoDB knew that deadlocks were a potential performance problem, and tried to make InnoDB rollback the transaction which had done "less work". Whichever transaction has done less work since it started, will be rolled back. So if one transaction has done a million inserts, and the other one has only done one, the one-insert transaction is likely to be rolled back.

InnoDB isn't very efficient at rolling back large transactions. In one system I saw a transaction take 45 minutes to roll back.

Generally speaking, if you find that you're getting a lot of deadlocks it may be because of an application design problem. For example, if you do huge update queries on a regular basis, this may be indicative that your database is insufficiently normalised (for instance).